# Output sound device changes automatically in Clementine

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, clementine, pavucontrol

I am using Clementine 1.2 on Kubuntu 14.04. I have the default sound card set to my USB headphones but I have Clementine set to use the HDMI output via pavucontrol. While playing from a playlist, when the audio file changes, there is a chance that the application will switch to the other device.

Is there something I can do or I should use different application like Amarok?

EDIT

I changed to Amarok and the issue did not happened ever again, would be good to know what causes it since I seen similar issues reported with tabs in browsers changing the output device

Answer (score 0):

My Clementine shows the same behaviour. Though I noticed, that if you switch off automatic crossfading and let the playlist run, it is much better. However if you manually skip to the next song, Clementine will change the audio device.

Comment: As a workaround Amarok has none of the issue.